# Attachments with ACTION.SENDTO intent on old devices

Tags: android, email, android-intent, email-attachments

I'm trying to have a user send a .csv file created through the app, but all the solutions I can find which allow the user to choose an email application aren't compatible with gingerbread, my compatibility goal. Finally, if I use ACTION_SEND instead of ACTION_SENDTO, then gmail crashes when trying to send the data and email doesn't add it as an attachment. Are there any ways around this, or do I have to lower my expectations?

Comment: whats is the crash saying? also show us some code.